# Exception occured while trying to use MsmqSubscription storage

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I am newbie in NService bus and I am trying to create a bus using MSMQSubscribtion storage , but I am getting following error.

> Exception when starting endpoint,
>   error has been logged. Reason: Error
>   creating object with name
>   'NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Msmq.MsmqSubscriptionStorage'
>   : Error setting property values:
>   PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1
>   errors); nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
>       [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:
>   Cannot convert property value of type
>   [System.String] to required type
>   [System.String] for property 'Queue'.,
>   Inner Exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: There is a
>   problem with the subscription storage
>   queue . See enclosed exception for
>   details. --->
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueueException:
>   Format name is invalid.
>          at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_Transactional()
>          at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_Transactional()
>          at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Msmq.MsmqSubscriptionStorage.set_Queue(String
>   value) in
>   d:\BuildAgent-02\work\672d81652eaca4e1\src\impl\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Msmq\MsmqSubscriptionStorage.cs:line
>   184
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Msmq.MsmqSubscriptionStorage.set_Queue(String
>   value) in
>   d:\BuildAgent-02\work\672d81652eaca4e1\src\impl\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.Msmq\MsmqSubscriptionStorage.cs:line
>   188
>          at (Object , Object , Object[] )
>          at Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeProperty.SetValue(Object
>   target, Object value) in
>   l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicProperty.cs:line
>   204
>          at Spring.Expressions.PropertyOrFieldNode.PropertyValueAccessor.Set(Object
>   context, Object value) in
>   l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Expressions\PropertyOrFieldNode.cs:line
>   585
>          at Spring.Expressions.PropertyOrFieldNode.SetPropertyOrFieldValueInternal(Object
>   context, Object newValue) in
>   l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Expressions\PropertyOrFieldNode.cs:line
>   406
>          at Spring.Expressions.PropertyOrFieldNode.SetPropertyOrFieldValue(Object
>   context, EvaluationContext
>   evalContext, Object newValue) in
>   l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Expressions\PropertyOrFieldNode.cs:line
>   348]

This is my Config section .

```
<configuration>
      <configSections>
      <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig,NServiceBus.Core"/>
      <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig,NServiceBus.Core"/>
      <section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig"
              type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig,NServiceBus.Core" />
      </configSections>

      <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyResponseQueue" ErrorQueue="error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>

      <UnicastBusConfig>
        <MessageEndpointMappings>
          <add Messages="MyMessages.Message1" Endpoint="PubQueue"/>
        </MessageEndpointMappings>
      </UnicastBusConfig>
    </configuration>
```

This is how I tried to create the bus

```
    NServiceBus.Configure.With()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        .Log4Net()
        .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
        .XmlSerializer()
        .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .UnicastBus()
        .CreateBus();
```

Can any one explain what went wrong for me?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Alex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the actual MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig section.  This is required and will point to your subscription queue.

```
<MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="queueName" />
```

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus will automatically use a queue called "NServiceBus_Subscriptions", if not defined in configuration file. Be sure to have installed MSMQ.

[image]